# Did Enter region delegate not firing on enter

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, gps, clregion

I can't seem to figure out why this function won't fire

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region:CLRegion) {
    println("here")
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Grab your bags "
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

I thought this fired upon entering or leaving a region thats being monitored, heres how i monitor my regions

```
var wholeFoodsRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: wholeFoods, radius: CLLocationDistance(33.0), identifier:"wholeFoods")
```

which is then put into an array and monitored like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < regions.count; i++){
        locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(regions[i])
    }
```

How an i get that function to fire upon entering a region

Comment: How many regions are you monitoring? There is a limit of 20, I think. Try setting your radius wider. Make sure you implement monitoringDidFailForRegion and check whether you are getting errors setting up the monitoring.

Comment: My code ended up being correct. I simply had too large a region and when getting in my car to test the app I did not drive far enough away to trigger the function. Thanks for your time thought!

Comment: It's a pretty cool feeling when you get location monitoring working!

Comment: No kidding! I still grin a little bit whenever I drive by and my phone goes off haha. Am I able to "vote" your response or "choose" it? I just made this account so I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: No need, I didn't really solve anything. Good luck on the rest of your app.